# Extracting similar variables in three dataframes in R

Tags: r

So currently, i have three dataframes:

```
>df1

 Variable      Val
    a          0.9
    g          0.3
    e          0.1

>df2

 Variable       Val
   h            0.2
   a            0.7
   e            0.9

>df3

 Variable       Val
   z            0.5
   a            0.7
   e            0.9
```

and I'm trying to extract the Variable which appears in all three dataframe, which is a and e in this case, since **a** and **e** appears in df1,df2,and df3.

Hence the output i wanted is:

```
[1] a  e
```

Which is just the variable, without the val.

I tried something like:

```
similar <- subset(df1, Variable%in% df2$Variable)
```

But it seemed like its only limited to two dataframes but not three?

Answer (score 0):

An option would be to place the datasets in a `list`, extract the 'variable' column and get the elements that are common with `intersect`

```
Reduce(intersect, lapply(mget(paste0("df", 1:3)), `[[`, "Variable"))
#[1] "a" "e"
```

---

Or similar option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidverse)
mget(paste0("df", 1:3)) %>%
      map(~ .x %>%
               pull(Variable)) %>%
      reduce(intersect)
#[1] "a" "e"
```

---

Or we bind the datasets into a single one, grouped by 'Variable', `filter` the number of unique groups equal to 3 and extract he 'Variable'

```
bind_rows(df1, df2, df3, .id = 'grp') %>%
     group_by(Variable) %>%
     filter(n_distinct(grp) == 3) %>%
     distinct(Variable) %>% 
     pull(Variable)
```

[1] "a" "e"

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Variable = c("a", "g", "e"), Val = c(0.9, 0.3, 
0.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df2 <- structure(list(Variable = c("h", "a", "e"), Val = c(0.2, 0.7, 
0.9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))

df3 <- structure(list(Variable = c("z", "a", "e"), Val = c(0.5, 0.7, 
0.9)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```